# Adding click event listeners to all divs in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've been trying to add an event listener for all of my divs using querySelectorAll in popup.html page to run a custom JS function. The number of divs returning is zero and can't seem to work out why. Any help would be appreciated.

popup.js

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
alert(divs.length);
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    var self = divs[i];
    self.addEventListenter('click', function (event) {
        testfunction('hi');
    }, false);
}

function testfunction(text) {
  alert(text);
}
```

popup.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
 <style>
 body {
    min-width:300px;
}
 </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
<div id="1">Link 1</div>
<div id="2">Link 2</div>
<div id="3">Link 3</div>
<div id="4">Link 4</div>
<div id="5">Link 5</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please do not use snippets unless it's supposed to be code that can be executed as an example _right here_. To format multi-line code, just precede each line with 4 spaces.

Comment: What is document referring to in the context of `popup.js`? IIRC popup.js isn't attached directly to the DOM of the page you're on.